# Remover SpellCheck (Verificar Ortografia)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, sharepoint

[image: Este Campo]

Preciso Remover o Campo de Verificar Ortografia da Barra Editar, porém não acho nenhuma propriedade ou como remover o campo, já removi todos os botões que eu não precisava mas não consigo achar a referencia desse, como resolver?

Answer (score 2):

Você pode customizar o Ribbon

```
File>Options>Customize Ribbon>Remova a aba ‘Editing’ (Editar)
```

Fonte: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4e2fa9ad-ca98-4c52-94a9-202f639e41e8/how-to-remove-spell-checker-button-form-sharepoint-2010-browsable-infopath-forms-ribbon?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious